# Is it possible to boot to a RAID1 btrfs root file with no initramfs?

Tags: btrfs, raid1

I currently switched my BTRFS-based gentoo system to using raid1 (basically a 2nd harddisk got unused, so I used it as raid1).

I could extend the btrfs filesystem with a second device in raid1 mode.
But since then grub2 will not boot any longer.
Is it possible to let grub2 boot into a btrfs root filesystem which uses raid1 (and is on a subvolume), without having an initramfs?
Until yet I never used an initramfs, because on gentoo this seems to be a bit too complex.

When I try booting, I only get kernel panics - it seems the kernel cannot properly mount the rootfs.
Until I switched to raid1 for the rootfs, though, the system **did** boot normally, so this seems to be caused by raid1.

Another related question - both partitions (sda5,sdb5) used for the rootfs have the same UUID. Is this normal?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to do so, but it can be unreliable.

You need to explicitly tell the kernel about each individual device of the volume using the `rootflags` parameter on the kernel command-line like so:

```
rootflags=device=/dev/sda5,device=/dev/sdb5
```

This has a couple of very specific limitations:

- It may not work if you're using an old kernel.  I've only done this on 4.10 and newer myself, but I know it did not work on some 3.x kernels.
- You can only use device paths for the `device=` values, and they have to be paths that aren't created by `udev`.  Without an initramfs, you don't have the luxury of using `blkid` to find devices, and you don't have links created by `udev` yet when you try to mount the root filesystem.
- You will need to manually update thisany time you change your partition layout.

As to your secondary question, yes, it is normal for each device in a BTRFS volume to share the same UUID.  UUID's as reported by `blkid` and similar tools are per-filesystem, not per-device, so a multi-device filesystem will show the same UUID for each component device.

Answer (score 0):

I did experiment with the "device=..." approach, but it did not work at all - I reliably got a kernel panic on startup.
This may be due to the fact that I am using 4.9.76 as kernel - maybe this only works for 4.10 or newer.
Anyways - I gave up, looked at https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Btrfs/Native_System_Root_Guide (I am using gentoo) and built an initramfs according to this guide.
If you follow this guide, though, you may also need to add following lines to the file *initramfs_list*:

```
    #some devices
    nod /dev/console 644 0 0 c 5 1
    nod /dev/tty0    644 0 0 c 4 0
```

Otherwise you may get a "cannot open initial console" error.

This initramfs based approach works now.